# Calculation of cost function by Iteration using Tensorflow

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow, initialization, calculation

I have the following code extraction for calculation of cost function with iteration. Before that, feature scaling, resharp, lstm and training have been done and using the same set of data and variables to perform the calculation of cost function.

```
# learning parameter
learning_rate = 0.01

# iterative parameters
EPOCHS = 1000 # number of iterations
PRINT_STEP = 100 # the interval of printing validation result

# read data and data preprocessings
read_data_pd = pd.read_csv('./price.csv')
input_pd = read_data_pd.drop(['year','month','day'], axis=1)
temp_pd = feature_scaling(input_pd[feature_to_scale],sacling_meathod) # call the function feature scaling
input_pd[feature_to_scale] = temp_pd
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, n_features])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

# call the lstm-rnn function
lstm_output = lstm(x_, n_features, batch_size, n_lstm_layers, lstm_scope_name)

# linear regressor
# w is the weight vector 
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, n_pred_class])) 
# b is the bias                                                                                                   
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_pred_class]))
# Y = WX + b 
y = tf.matmul(lstm_output, W) + b

#define the cost function
cost_func = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_func)

# initialize all variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()        
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for ii in range(EPOCHS):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x_:train_input_nparr, y_:train_target_nparr})
        if ii % PRINT_STEP == 0:
            cost = sess.run(cost_func, feed_dict={x_:train_input_nparr, y_:train_target_nparr})
            print 'iteration =', ii, 'training cost:', cost
```

When I run the program, the print of calculation results of cost function is work. Yet, each time when the program runs, the results is different. For example, the results of 100 iteration sometimes will print 0.868856, but sometime might be 0.905526, which means the code have some problem.

One thing I noticed is the lines with initialize all variables: `tf.initialize_all_variables()` as message said that

```
initialize_all_variables is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating: Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
```

I follow the instruction, but it has no effect to amend the calculation error.

Therefore, I would like to know what is wrong with the codes and also how to correct it?

Comment: why do you assume it has an error? the weights are initialized randomly and you compare at only 100 iterations...

Comment: The weights are initialized randomly and maybe you are shuffling your training data for each training epoch.

Comment: Most probably your learning rate is too high and the network has not converged yet. Reduce the learning rate and keep going with training.